# How to access specific column value in specific row in surveyJS

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I have a dynamic matrix (inside a panel) with 4 single line text columns and one boolean column.

In another dynamic panel I have a second dynamic matrix that is supposed to show ONLY those items where in the first matrix the user set the boolean value to true.

I can manage to show the first row but as soon as I add a second row in the first matrix, the "view only" row is deleted. If I set the value of the second row to true, the matrix shows up again but the data is from the first entry.

How can I use that one specific column value per row for the "visibleIf" condiiton? Or is there an altogether different way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the [rowsVisibleIf](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/matrix-table-question-model#rowsVisibleIf) expression of the second matrix to show only those items which were selected in the first matrix:

```
"rowsVisibleIf": "{matrix1} contains {item}",
```

Please refer to the following demo for more details: .